"App Not Installed" msg on Fire TV Max 2 Gen
After developed fire tv app using android emulator, I installed on fire tv and google tv.
On google tv, it works fine.
But following msg is shown on fire tv.
"App Not Installed".
Please help me.
I want to proper work on fire tv.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
